# What is the term for this type of refactoring

Tags: terminology, refactoring

I am sure there is a term for the following bit of refactoring, but I can't remember it and my Google-fu is failing me!

The refactor moves if statements to where they are going to have most impact, for example changing this

```
$test = someFunctionThatReturnsABool();
for($x = 0; $x < 10000; $x++) {
    if ($test) { 
        echo $x; 
    }
}
```

To this

```
$test = someFunctionThatReturnsABool();
if ($test) {
    for($x = 0; $x < 10000; $x++) {
        echo $x; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is [loop-invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion). A good compiler should do it on its own.

> ...**loop-invariant code** consists of statements or expressions (in an [imperative programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)) which can be moved outside the body of a loop without affecting the semantics of the program. **Loop-invariant code motion** (also called **hoisting** or **scalar promotion**) is a [compiler optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization) which performs this movement automatically...
>
> If we consider the following code sample, two optimizations can be easily applied.
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>     x = y + z;
>     a[i] = 6 * i + x * x;
> }
> ```
>
> The calculation `x = y + z` and `x * x` can be moved outside the loop since within they are [loop invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) — they do not change over the iterations of the loop— so the optimized code will be something like this:
>
> ```
> x = y + z;
> t1 = x * x;
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>     a[i] = 6 * i + t1;
> }
> ```
>
> This code can be optimized further...

Comment: a good programmer should do it on it's own as well, I guess

Comment: I agree @stijn - there are some things that it is reasonable to let the compiler worry about, but this isn't one of them!

Comment: @Toby: While this is true for new code (after all, the loop-invariant move makes for an easier-understood inner loop), anything that is already done by the compiler doesn't need to be done by hand. I'd just let old code such as the above example stand; the quality improvement of LICM is small and probably not worth your time.

Comment: @thiton I disagree.  Leaving it as-is will mean all future maintainers would have to go through the same reasoning.  It wastes time; just change it.

Comment: @stijn, this sort of pattern is easily hidden among other code, which can make it harder for a programmer (even a good one) to find.

Comment: @zzzzBov if you mean hidden, as in nested deeply in other functions in a loop, then likely it shouldn't be found nor optimized because it doesn't matter: you cannot expect anyone writing a loop having to bother about what the underlying calls will do all the way down to assembly level. If you mean hidden beacause there's too much code in the loop, I'd say that's a violation of SRP or just plain bad code.

Comment: Depending on the scope of $test, it may be impossible for the compiler to determine that $test cannot be changed by the loop body.  I do this optimization myself since doing so clarifies the code.

Comment: @stijn, "In theory, theory and practice are the same; in practice they are not." - you're overlooking the concept of development as a process. A programmer doesn't just write code and forget it, they write code and then add to it. If you start with a loop of two operations happening on the entire set of elements (`for (...) { foo(); bar(); }`) it would be easy to overlook this issue when a third operation is added which matches this pattern (`for (...) { foo(); baz(); bar(); }`, `baz` begins with `if (test) {...}`).

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm not overlooking anything, I covered your example in my comment alread when talking about nested fuctions: it does not matter in those cases. What if `baz()` begins with `xxx()` which begins with `yyy()` which calls `zzz()` which uses `if( test ) { ... }`? You shouldn't care. (unless the code gets called gazillion times and the profiler says it's THE bottleneck)

Comment: @stijn, I agree that premature optimization is the root of all evil, I'm just defending my original comment that "this sort of pattern is easily hidden among other code".

Comment: @zzzzBov yes I know, but my point is that when the pattern is hidden, it probably isn't exactly the pattern anymore. Or something like that. (sorry, long day)

Comment: This will have different meaning depending on what the conditional actually does and if there is an else inside the for loop.

Answer (score 10):

This is also called `hoisting` or `scalar promotion`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430095/are-hoisting-and-reordering-the-same-thing):

> Hoisting means that you have pulled some operation out of a loop
>   because the loop itself does not affect the result of the operation.
>   In your case, you are hoisting the conditional test out of the while
>   loop.
>
> Re-ordering means changing the sequence of instructions in a way that
>   does not affect the result. Typically this would be adjacent
>   instructions with no data dependencies, e.g. it does not matter which
>   order you perform the following two statements:
>
> ```
> int a = x;
> int b = y;
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a variant of Remove Control Flag (pp 245 of Fowler's [Refactoring](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Technology/dp/0201485672))

A PHP example can be [found on DZone](http://agile.dzone.com/articles/practical-php-refactoring-23).

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think such a refactoring exists.**

So, it would be hard to find it amongst ''lists of refactorings''.

I'd class that example  as an **optimisation** not a **refactoring**.

Refactoring, to me, is changing the code to improve its understandability without affecting its behaviour.

Optimisation, to me, is changing the code to improve performance.

Since optimised code tends to be less easy to understand. The two practices tend to work against each other.